# Jquery to javascript. Post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Friends, I'm converting Jquery to javascript and I'm having problems with this block of code:

```
$.post('ajax_data',{action:'service_price',service:service,quantity:quantity,dripfeed:dripfeed,runs:runs}, function(data){
        $("#charge").val(data.price);
        $("#dripfeed-totalquantity").val(data.totalQuantity);
    }, 'json');
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work for me

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "ajax_data";
const params = "action=service_price&service=" + service + "&quantity=" + quantity+ "&dripfeed=" + dripfeed+ "&runs=" + runs;
request.responseType =  "json";
request.open("POST", url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 
request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
 
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        let data = request.response;
      document.querySelector("#charge").val(data.price);
      document.querySelector("#dripfeed-totalquantity").val(data.totalQuantity);
    }
});
request.send(params);
```

Comment: `new XMLHTTPRequest` is a little old-school. Have you looked at the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Comment: missing '=' after ’&service‘

Comment: Fetch API I have not tried to use. I will study

Comment: missing '=' after '&service' - yes, fixed it. But the problem remained.

Comment: [doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem. Please read [ask]. Tell us what actually happens. Use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to see what request actually gets sent.

Comment: Don't generate URLEncoded data by mashing strings together (especially when you forget to escape special characters in them). Use [a URLSearchParams object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead.

Comment: Open the developer tools console and read the error messages. I'd expect there to be an obvious error telling you that `val` isn't a function.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).val is not a function
    myClickHandler .../public/ajaxjavascript.js:43
    myClickHandler .../public/ajaxjavascript.js:39

LINE 39 -> request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
LINE 43 ->  document.querySelector("#charge").val(data.price);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
async function postData(url = "", data = {}) { //https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}


postData('ajax_data', {action:'service_price',service:service,quantity:quantity,dripfeed:dripfeed,runs:runs}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```html
let url = 'ajax_data';
let params = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: 'action=service_price&service=' + encodeURIComponent(service) + '&quantity=' + quantity + '&dripfeed=' + dripfeed + '&runs=' + runs
};
fetch(url, params)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
    .then(data => {
        document.querySelector('#charge').value = data.price;
        document.querySelector('#dripfeed-totalquantity').value = data.totalQuantity;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work. This code does not work, but there are no errors in the logs either (minus is not mine)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.